# How can I set class object in NS dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2

Hello I am new to programming so may be this question makes no sense to you. well I wanted to do is I have created a model class and I am setting a variables there by creating a class object. Now I have to pass these values to  server so that it can be save into database.

at the moment I put variables in the dictionary and send to server like this

```
   let params =
        [
        "email":user.email,
        "password":user.password,
        "first_name":user.firstName,
        "last_name":user.lastName
        ]
```

lets say if I have 10 variables, I don't want to assign each of them like this. I want something like this

```
   let params = [user]
```

so that I directly pass an object without doing it again manually...I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You can't do that directly but you can write a custom function to do that.

Comment: could you write a demo function ?@vadian

Comment: See Eric's answer, that's pretty suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a computed property in your User class which will create the params for you. Something like this example:

```
class User {
    var email = "a@test.com"
    var password = "123"
    var firstName = "joe"
    var lastName = "abc"
    var params: [String:String] {
        return [
            "email": self.email,
            "password": self.password,
            "first_name": self.firstName,
            "last_name": self.lastName
        ]
    }

}

let user = User()

let params = user.params  // ["first_name": "joe", "last_name": "abc", "email": "a@test.com", "password": "123"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... what If I have integer values too then?

Comment: Can I use this ? var params: [String:Any] .. It works but I want to get your opinion

Comment: You can use AnyObject for the value type, yes.